# matching the column of excel of a list of python

Tags: python

I have an Excel sheet where it has 2 columns. The 1st is `ingredient` and the 2nd is `tag` and I have a sentence. I want to compare the value of ingredient column to the string. If the word is matched, then add it into new list. For this purpose my code is here:

```py
    import nltk
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
    import pandas as pd

    setence="I like carrot Apple wine"
    word =word_tokenize(setence.lower())
    l=[]

    data=pd.read_excel('items.xlsx')
    print(data["ingredients"])
    for item in data["ingredients"]:

     if item in word:
         print(item)
         l.append(item)


    print(l)
```

The Excel sheet contains these values:

```
 0     apple
 1     wine 
 2    carrot
 3       egg
 4       CUP
```

The output of the code is:

```py
['apple', 'carrot']
```

But it didn't match wine?

Comment: can't you just do if item in setence.lower()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your code with the same sample data, I recognize that `'wine '` in `data['ingredients']` has whitespace, while `'wine'` in `word` doesn't have.

My suggestion to avoid this issue is using `strip()`: `if item.strip() in word:`

Code:

```py
#...
for item in data["ingredients"]:
    if item.strip() in word:
        print(item)
#...
```

Output:

```
apple
wine 
carrot
```

Comment: its helpfull for mee

Comment: @ShahWajahat you can upvote and mark it as the right answer